# Properly finalize flow from callbackFlow

Tags: android, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, kotlin-flow

In the example below, I simply wrote a callbackflow example.

```
    var listener: ((String) -> Unit)? = null
    fun callback1() {
        listener?.let{
            it("1")
        }
    }

    fun callback2() {
        listener?.let{
            it("2")
        }
    }

    fun fromRepository(): Flow<String> = callbackFlow {
        listener = { result->
            trySend(result)
        }
        awaitClose {
            listener = null
        }
    }

    fun test() {
        val job = lifecycleScope.launch {
            fromRepository()
                .onCompletion { Timber.d("Completed") }
                .collectLatest {
                    Timber.d("Number: $it")
                }
        }
        callback1()
        callback2()
        callback1()
    }
```

I can see 1,2,1 output on the log as a result of the example code above.
but even if I set `listener = null` the job continues to run. I edited the `test` function a bit for this.

```
    fun test() {
        val job = lifecycleScope.launch {
            fromRepository()
                .onCompletion { Timber.d("Completed") }
                .collectLatest {
                    Timber.d("Number: $it")
                }
        }
        callback1()
        callback2()
        callback1()
        listener = null

        lifecycleScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
            delay(1000)
            Timber.d("job status: ${job.isActive}")
        }
    }
```

In addition to the above output, I can now see `job status: true` as well.

How can I completely finish the flow in the example above. How can I be protected from memory leak in this situation?

```
                .collectLatest {
                    Timber.d("Number: $it")
                    cancel()
                }
```

If I use the `cancel` function, it happens as I want, both the `job becomes false` and the `onCompletion function calls`. Is there any other solution without using the Cancel function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I completely finish the flow in the example above. How can I be protected from memory leak in this situation?

I guess it depends on what you're trying to do. A flow built with `callbackFlow` can be completed in several ways.

On the producer side, you can `close()` the backing channel (from inside `callbackFlow`), and this will have the effect of completing the flow from the consumer's point of view (a `collect` call will complete and return).

On the consumer side, you can cancel the collection of the flow. This can be done by using operators such as `first()` or `take(5)` that will stop the collection without waiting for the flow to actually complete. It can also be done by cancelling the coroutine in which the `collect` call happens.